# c++ netplan ubuntu yaml read and create

Tags: c++, yaml, netplan

i have create a c++ app and need to read Ubuntu Netplan yaml files.
I found many websites with a lot of helpful information. mostly everything just does not work with netplan files. it crashes every time, usually when I set the root node to network. However, it is necessary because you still do not know what network card it is.

```
network.yaml

    network: 
        ethernets: 
          eth0: 
            addresses: 
              - 192.168.0.30/24
            dhcp4: false
            gateway4: "192.168.0.1"
            nameservers: 
              addresses: 
                - "211.211.190.30"
                - "211.160.60.1"
                - "8.8.8.8"
              search: 
                - Network.local
        renderer: networkd
        version: 2
```

it must save into a struct for another works.

- [Parsing yaml with yaml cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492397/parsing-yaml-with-yaml-cpp)
- [yaml-cpp Easiest way to iterate through a map with undefined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374691/yaml-cpp-easiest-way-to-iterate-through-a-map-with-undefined-values)
- [yaml-cpp read sequence in item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368135/yaml-cpp-read-sequence-in-item)
- http://albertocorona.com/yaml-cpp-a-small-tutorial-to-serialization/

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <yaml-cpp/node/node.h>
#include <yaml-cpp/node/iterator.h>

using namespace std;

static string path02 = "/Netzwerk.yaml";


struct NetInfo {
    int             ID;
    string          version;
    string          renderer;
    string          IF_Type;
    string          name;
    string          dhcp4;
    vector<string>  addresseIF;
    string          gateway4;
    vector<string>  NSsearch;
    vector<string>  NSaddress;
};

int main(){
    NetInfo yamlsafe;
    YAML::Node config = YAML::LoadFile(path02);
    string NetzwerkTyp = config["network"]["ethernets"].as<std::string>();
    string NetzManager = config["network"]["renderer"].as<string>();
    string If_Name     = config["network"]["eth0"].as<string>();
    string DHCP4       = config["eth0"]["addresses"].as<string>();
    string IP          = config["eth0"]["dhcp4"].as<string>();
    string Gateway     = config["eth0"]["gateway4"].as<string>();
    string NS_IP       = config["nameservers"]["addresses"].as<string>();
    string NS_Search   = config["nameservers"]["search"].as<string>();

    cout <<"NetzwerkTyp:"  << "\t" << NetzwerkTyp << endl;
    cout <<"Netz Manager:" << "\t" << NetzManager << endl;
    cout <<"If-Name:"      << "\t" << If_Name     << endl;
    cout <<"DHCP4"         << "\t" << DHCP4       << endl;
    cout <<"IP"            << "\t" << IP          << endl;
    cout <<"Gateway"       << "\t" << Gateway     << endl;
    cout <<"NS-IP"         << "\t" << NS_IP       << endl;
    cout <<"NS-Search"     << "\t" << NS_Search   << endl;

    //second test 
    YAML::Node config1 = YAML::LoadFile(path02);
    const YAML::Node& sensors = config1["network"];
    for (YAML::const_iterator it = sensors.begin(); it != sensors.end(); ++it) {
        const YAML::Node& sensor = *it;
        std::cout << "address: " << sensor["addresses"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
        std::cout << "dhcp: " << sensor["dhcp4"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;

}
```

yes i had the same think i've bin see this tipe but 
nothing is what it makes. it hange up the QT ide.
my second thing is the second test below.

```
    YAML::Node config1 = YAML::LoadFile(path02);
    const YAML::Node& node1 = config1["network"];
    //network: ------------------------>node2
        const YAML::Node& node2 = node1["network"]["ethernets"];
    //    ethernets: ------------------>node3
           const YAML::Node& node3 = node2["ethernets"]["eth0"];
    //      eth0: --------------------->node4
              const YAML::Node& node4 = node3["eth0"]["addresses"];
    //        addresses: ----------------------N1-> - seq1
                const vector& node4s1 = node4["addresses"];
    //          - 192.168.0.30/24-----------------> - seq1 -p1
              const YAML::Node& node4 = node3["eth0"]["dhcp4"];
    //        dhcp4: false ------------------>node4-2
              const YAML::Node& node4 = node3["eth0"]["gateway4"];
    //        gateway4: "192.168.0.1"-------->node4-3
              const YAML::Node& node4 = node3["eth0"]["nameservers"];
    //        nameservers: ------------------>node4-4
                const vector& node4s2 = node4["nameservers"]["addresses"];
    //          addresses: --------------------N5-> - seq2
    //            - "211.211.190.30"--------------> - seq2 - p1
    //            - "211.160.60.1"----------------> - seq2 - p2
    //            - "8.8.8.8"---------------------> - seq2 - p3
                const vector& node4s3 = node4["nameservers"]["search"];
    //          search: -----------------------N6-> - seq3 
    //            - Network.local-----------------> - seq3 - p1
         const YAML::Node& node2 = node1["network"]["renderer"];
    //    renderer: networkd---------->node5
         const YAML::Node& node2 = node1["network"]["version"];
    //    version: 2------------------>node6
```

this is what i thing about it but it is not working.

Comment: I don't know about how the lookup works on the object `config` in C++, but I would expect `config["network"]["eth0"]`  to be fully written as `config["network"]["ethernets"]["eth0"]`, as in the mapping that is the value for `network` there is no key `eth0`

Comment: Yes i know that, but in that i works with nodes only all front words in that yaml file identify as node and i became my output. The problem with eth0 is that is the interface for a networkcard and in a dynamic process it is difficult when a referenz point occurse in it self. I have it taste with keys and values but all points of that file key and values at same time. When i use mapping and sequenz it is no point to refer it. also i became the same output for key and value. I dont know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is the answer i have a struct and i can read all nodes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <yaml-cpp/node/iterator.h>

using namespace std;

struct DateiLesen {
    string version;
    string renderer;
    string IF_Type;
    string name;
    string dhcp4;
    string dhcp6;
    vector<string> addresseIF;
    string gateway4;
    string gateway6;
    vector<string> NSsearch;
    vector<string> NSaddress;
};
static vector<DateiLesen> DLS2;

static string path = "/QTProjects/YAML-15/test/Netzwerk.yaml";

void Yaml_lesen(){
    YAML::Node nodew = YAML::LoadFile(path);
    string NetIf = "eth0";

    DLS2.push_back(DateiLesen());

    if (nodew["network"]) {
        if (nodew["network"]["version"]) {
            DLS2[0].version = nodew["network"]["version"].as<string>();
            //std::cout << nodew["network"]["version"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
        }
        if (nodew["network"]["renderer"]) {
            DLS2[0].renderer = nodew["network"]["renderer"].as<std::string>();
            //std::cout << nodew["network"]["renderer"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
        }
        if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"]) {
            DLS2[0].IF_Type = "ethernets";
            if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]) {
                if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["dhcp4"]) {
                    DLS2[0].dhcp4 = nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["dhcp4"].as<string>();
                    //std::cout << nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["dhcp4"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                }
                if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["dhcp6"]) {
                    DLS2[0].dhcp6 = nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["dhcp6"].as<string>();
                    //std::cout << nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["dhcp6"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                }
                if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["addresses"]) {
                    if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["addresses"].IsSequence()) {
                        for (unsigned long it = 0; it < nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["addresses"].size(); ++it) {
                            DLS2[0].addresseIF.push_back(nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["addresses"][it].as<std::string>());
                            //cout << nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["addresses"][it].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["gateway4"]) {
                    DLS2[0].gateway4 = nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["gateway4"].as<string>();
                    //std::cout << nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["gateway4"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                }
                if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["gateway6"]) {
                    DLS2[0].gateway6 = nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["gateway6"].as<string>();
                    //std::cout << nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["gateway4"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                }
                if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["nameservers"]) {
                    //cout << "Nameservers" << endl;
                    if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["search"]) {
                        if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["search"].IsSequence()) {
                            for (unsigned long it = 0; it < nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["search"].size(); ++it) {
                                DLS2[0].NSsearch.push_back(nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["search"][it].as<std::string>());
                                //cout << nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["search"][it].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["addresses"]) {
                        if (nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["addresses"].IsSequence()) {
                            for (unsigned long it = 0; it < nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["addresses"].size(); ++it) {
                                DLS2[0].NSaddress.push_back(nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["addresses"][it].as<std::string>());
                                //cout << nodew["network"]["ethernets"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["addresses"][it].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else if(nodew["network"]["wifis"]){
            DLS2[0].IF_Type = "wifis";
            if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]) {
                if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["dhcp4"]) {
                    DLS2[0].dhcp4 = nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["dhcp4"].as<string>();
                    //std::cout << nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["dhcp4"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                }
                if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["dhcp6"]) {
                    DLS2[0].dhcp6 = nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["dhcp6"].as<string>();
                    //std::cout << nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["dhcp6"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                }
                if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["addresses"]) {
                    if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["addresses"].IsSequence()) {
                        for (unsigned long it = 0; it < nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["addresses"].size(); ++it) {
                            DLS2[0].addresseIF.push_back(nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["addresses"][it].as<std::string>());
                            //cout << nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["addresses"][it].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["gateway4"]) {
                    DLS2[0].gateway4 = nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["gateway4"].as<string>();
                    //std::cout << nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["gateway4"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                }
                if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["gateway6"]) {
                    DLS2[0].gateway6 = nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["gateway6"].as<string>();
                    //std::cout << nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["gateway4"].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                }
                if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["nameservers"]) {
                    cout << "Nameservers" << endl;
                    if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["search"]) {
                        if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["search"].IsSequence()) {
                            for (unsigned long it = 0; it < nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["search"].size(); ++it) {
                                DLS2[0].NSsearch.push_back(nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["search"][it].as<std::string>());
                                //cout << nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["search"][it].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["addresses"]) {
                        if (nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["addresses"].IsSequence()) {
                            for (unsigned long it = 0; it < nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["addresses"].size(); ++it) {
                                DLS2[0].NSaddress.push_back(nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["addresses"][it].as<std::string>());
                                //cout << nodew["network"]["wifis"][NetIf]["nameservers"]["addresses"][it].as<std::string>() << "\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }else if(nodew["network"]["bonds"]){

        }else if(nodew["network"]["bridges"]){

        }else if(nodew["network"]["vlans"]){

        }
    }
}

int main(){
    Yaml_lesen();

    for (unsigned long S = 0; S < DLS2.size(); S++){
        cout << DLS2[S].renderer << endl;
        cout << DLS2[S].name << endl;
        cout << DLS2[S].IF_Type << endl;
        cout << DLS2[S].dhcp4 << endl;
        for (unsigned long S2 = 0; S2 < DLS2[S].addresseIF.size(); S2++){
            cout << DLS2[S].addresseIF[S2] << endl;
        }
        cout << DLS2[S].gateway4 << endl;
        for (unsigned long S2 = 0; S2 < DLS2[S].addresseIF.size(); S2++){
            cout << DLS2[S].NSsearch[S2] << endl;
        }
        for (unsigned long S2 = 0; S2 < DLS2[S].addresseIF.size(); S2++){
            cout << DLS2[S].NSaddress[S2] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```